# Resource leak warning on file stream

Tags: android, file-io, resource-leak

```
private void SaveLog(boolean externalStorage)
{
    String s = tv_log.getText().toString();
    File file;
    FileOutputStream fos;

    if ( externalStorage )
    {
        try
        {
            file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), FILE_LOG);
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);  // Warning: Resource leak: 'fos' is never closed
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            fos = openFileOutput(FILE_LOG, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
    }


    try
    {
        fos.write(s.getBytes());
        fos.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
}
```

Why the warning is shown in the line `fos = new FileOutputStream(file)`? Interesting, that if I remove `if ( externalStorage )` and leave only the first branch, the warning is not shown:

```
private void SaveLog(boolean externalStorage)
{
    String s = tv_log.getText().toString();
    File file;
    FileOutputStream fos;

    try
    {
        file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), FILE_LOG);
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);  // OK!
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        fos.write(s.getBytes());
        fos.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: What warning? Posting code is good, but please explain the *issue*.

Comment: fos = new FileOutputStream(file);  // Warning: Resource leak: 'fos' is never closed

Comment: @shkschneider - warning text is in the comments, first program fragment.

Comment: Looks like Lint bug, the program is OK.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that in your specific case there isn't any possibility of resource leak as the line `fos = new FileOutputStream(file);`is the last line before the end of the `try` group, and if you have an exception in here the resource `fos` wouldn´t be created.

However, if you would have a statement after that line, that statement could genetare a exception, the execution would move to the `catch` group that is terminated with a return without releasing resources allocated in the `try`group.

The easiest way to avoid the warning is to add the following in the `catch`:

```
catch(FileNotFoundException e) 
{ 
    try { if(fos != null) fos.close();} catch (Exception e2) {} //Add this line
    Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    return; 
}
```

This would ensure that resource will be released if there is an exception raised.

Comment: This is not compiled. Please post tested solution.

Comment: Just for your info, your original code doesn't raise any warning in the editor I'm using `Eclipse`.

Comment: With try-catch this is compiled, but original warning remains, and new warning "Dead code" is added for fos.close line.

Comment: because you are only catcinhg `FileNotFoundException`. Replace `FileNotFoundException` by `Exception` and it will be gone.

Comment: Doesn't help. Please don't guess, this is not so simple al it looks.

Answer (score 0):

In every catch block, close the stream using `fos.close()`.

Otherwise, the program might hit the try block, generate an exception and go to the catch block without ever closing the stream. This might be causing the error.